# Java - Abstract class into normal class

Tags: java, class, abstract

```
public abstract class Figure
{
  private int offset;

  public Figure()
  {
    offset = 0;
  }

  public Figure(int theOffset)
  {
    offset = theOffset;
  }

  public void setOffset(int newOffset)
  {
    offset = newOffset;
  }

  public int getOffset()
  {
    return offset;
  }

  public abstract void drawHere();

  /**
   * Draws the figure at lineNumber lines down from the
   * current line.
   */

  public void drawAt(int lineNumber)
  {
    int count;
    for(count = 0; count < lineNumber; count++)
      System.out.println();
    drawHere();
  }
}
```

In this class, it handles the figure for creating a tree. I am trying to turn it into a normal class by simply giving a body to the abstract method. I noticed that when I remove the abstract tags, it still works perfectly normal. But my question is, if I want to make the class non-abstract, through what means would I go through to do this?

This class is extended upon by 2 other classes and then it has the main class. Do I have to go through and modify those too?

Comment: The two classes that extend upon Figure are Box and Triangle, they are not abstract. The only class that is abstract is Figure. Would I make a method that draws the figure in place of the 'public abstract void drawHere();' to finalize the removal of the abstract? This is meant as an exercise to emphasize the ease of use of the abstract tag.

Comment: Yes, so Box and Triangle provide their versions of "draw here" behavior.  No, you don't provide a method in the abstract Figure class - can you see why?  That only works if you know of a default behavior that can apply to all subclasses that extend it.  That cannot be true for Figure.  For goodness sake, leave poor Figure alone.  Do not touch it.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be altering Figure; you should be extending it.

> This class is extended upon by 2 other
>   classes and then it has the main
>   class. Do I have to go through and
>   modify those too?

All the more reason to not alter Figure: you'll break the rest of the code.

You should not be modifying anything.  Create a new class that extends Figure and override the abstract drawHere() method with the behavior you want.

Answer (score 2):

When you have an abstract class,

```
abstract class AbstractCar {

    float maxSpeed;
    Driver whoIsDriving;

    AbstractCar(float ms, Driver d) {
        maxSpeed = ms;
        if(!validateDriver(d)) throw new InvalidDriverException();
        whoIsDriving = d;
    }

    abstract boolean validateDriver(Driver d);

}
```

You can define the behavior separately for various conditions by extending and defining the abstract methods in question.

```
class CrappyCar extends AbstractCar {    
    boolean validateDriver(Driver d) {
        return d.hasLicense() && d.hasInsurance();
    }
}

class ExpensiveCar extends AbstractCar {
    boolean validateDriver(Driver d) {
        return d.hasLicense() && d.hasInsurance() && d.hasGoodJobInCaseHeMessesUpMyCar();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a non-abstract class, then you must not declare it with the `abstract` modifier (i.e. just `public class Figure`).  There shouldn't be any need to modify any derived classes (so long as they themselves are not abstract).

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, in order to make an abstract class non-abstract you have to:

- Provide implementation for all abstract methods
- Since you now have a valid implementation of everything define, remove all abstract tags

There is no need to modify anything in inheriting classes (assuming they are non-abstract theirselves) because they already provide an implementation of all the abstract methods of their parent & are free to override any method they wish.

Whether or not you should make your class non-abstract is another point of discussion.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that removing the `abstract` keywords and implementing the abstract methods makes the class non-abstract.

However, you normally do not want to turn the class itself from abstract to non-abstract. A class is not abstract until you add this keyword, so you (or someone else) apparently had a reason to make sure it's not a normal class, but an abstract one.

If you think about it at a very high level (far from Java), then a "Tree" is something you know how to draw. Similarly, you could imagine a subclass "Circle" for which you know what a drawing shoud look like. For the very generic "Figure", however, you have no idea what it means to draw it.

This is the idea of why the actual drawing is left `abstract` in your `Figure` class. Hence, you should not make `Figure` non-abstract, but instead focus on the classes that extend from it and make those non-abstract, by implementing all abstract methods from `Figure`. In your `Tree` class, you know what `drawHere` should do, so implement it there to print a tree. In another class, like `Circle` you implement it differently, but it never really makes sense to implement it in `Figure`, where you have no idea what to draw.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a method body for `drawHere()` (presumably empty, since, as @Frank pointed out, you can't really have any idea about how to draw a `Figure`) and remove the `abstract` modifiers. Then you will have a concrete class. That means someone could create a `new Figure()`. This won't be either of the two subclasses you now have, just a `Figure`.

If such an object (that does nothing when it is called upon to `drawHere()`) would not be useful (and, in particular, if you would consider it an error to have such an object), then you should keep the class abstract. This reasoning applies even when you can define an implementation for every method.

Answer (score 0):

If a class is made abstract you can give body to all the methodes or none of these but if any class is extending abstract class it must implement all the methode which is only being declared.